# Controls.Remove removing from controls but not from window

Tags: c#

I'm trying to recreate a game in C# and I have a control that is composed with 3 objects:

- A personalized PictureBox with an animated image [Player],
- And two other animated PictureBox with the orbs that are suposed to launch [Orbs].

The problem is, I have this code:

```
Orb[,] map = orbsAmmo;

for (Int32 x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < 2; y++)
        orbsAmmo[x, y] = null;

for (Int32 index = this.Controls.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    if (this.Controls[index] is Orb) {
        this.Controls[index].Parent = null;
        //this.Controls[index].Dispose();
        this.Controls.RemoveAt(index);
    }

//GC.Collect();

return map;
```

That works fine and removes the controls from the controls list, but the two Orbs that are supposed to be launched are still in the same location. If I try to see if the controls list still have the Orbs only appears the PictureBox of the Player.

I added the `GC.Collect();` to collect the garbage, nothing happened.

It is something that I'm not seeing or missing?

---

**SOLVED**

Basically, the error occurs when I create the Orbs, I had `Orb.parent = PictureBox` to overlay correctly the images, because of the transparency, and doing that piece of code I had to remove the Orbs from the PictureBox and not from the main control, like I was trying to do.

Now it works fine and correctly.

Comment: Take out the GC.Collect(). It won't help you and may actually have some negative side effects.

Comment: Could it be that the window just needs re-drawing? Try invalidating the parent. If that works then invalidate the parent where the control was (so it just draws that bit).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn GC.Collect() removed

Comment: @noelicus Nothing happens...

Comment: @Auhmaan: try calling this.Invalidate(); at the end to be redrawn everything

Comment: What do you mean by "are supposed to be launched". I thought you were trying to remove them?

Comment: @noelicus I'll remove the from this control and will add them to another control that is the board.

Comment: Then don't dispose it!

Comment: @noelicus Still nothing...

Comment: i think since its controls inside usercontrol is make a method in your Orb class to remove the desired controls.

Comment: What UI library are you using? WPF? Winforms? Metro? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (Int32 index = this.Controls.Count - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    if (this.Controls[index] is Orb) {
        this.Controls[index].Parent = null;
        //this.Controls[index].Dispose();
        this.Controls.RemoveAt(index);
    }
```

This code is buggy and will randomly remove controls.  A control *must* have a Parent.  If you set it to null then it will be **removed** from the parent's Control collection.  You will now call RemoveAt() for *another* control.  This may well be control that is not an Orb.

Calling the Dispose() method is *not* optional for controls.  When you remove them from their Parent then they'll be re-hosted to the hidden parking window.  Where they'll live, ready to moved to another parent.  With high odds that this never happens, your program will *leak* controls.  This cannot go endlessly, Windows refuses to allow you to create more windows after you've consumed 10,000 of them.

Not exactly a match with the complaint.  Another thing that needs to happen for a control to visibly disappear is for the parent to repaint its background.  Broken painting is common in gaming code.

Comment: First, I don't think that the code is buggy, it works fine.
Second, Adding controls by code doesn't give them "parents", I only set the parent because I'm working with images and setting the Parent option the image works correctly.
Third, Removing the parent doesn't remove them from the Control.Controls, it just remove the connection from Parent <-> Child that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

if you are `clearing/disposing` Controls by `index` you will be definitely missing some of them because each time you clear/dispose a control their `index will be changed`.

**Example** : if you remove  a `Control` at `index0` -> control at index 1 becomes index 0, so next time when you  try to remove control at `index 1` you will skip to clear control at `index 0`

Try This:

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```

or

```
this.ControlPanel.Controls.Clear();
```

Comment: That's beacause I start removing the items from the final and heading to 0. And the Clear() option IS NOT what I want, will remove one component that has to be there.
The ControlPanel does not exist.

Comment: @Auhmaan: great point , but from your code i saw that you are removing all controls? anyhow if you want to remove controls on specific panel you can invoke `this.PanelName.Controls.Clear()` check my edit

Comment: If you see the code again you gonna see that I have an if() checking if it is the control that I want to remove. And the second option doesn't work...

Comment: @DownVoter care to explain

Comment: @Sudhakar By looping backwards through the indices, this problem is avoided entirely. Also, the OP wants to remove some of the controls, not `clear` them all. The OP already commented on both of these issues above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `foreach` and `linq` to dispose the `orbs`

```
IEnumerable<Control> c = GetAllOrbs(this);

foreach (Orb item in c.ToArray())
{
    item.Dispose();
    //or if you prefer just to remove them use this:
    //item.Parent.Controls.Remove(item);
}
```

.

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAllOrbs(Control control)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAllOrbs(ctrl, type)).Concat(controls).Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(Orb));
}
```

You question is not clear, but from what i see in the code you want to remove the orbs.

Comment: Already tried the Dispose() option, didn't work. Basically I'm trying to remove Controls from the window, but somehow the Remove() doesn't work...

Comment: @nicolas and like that if there are controls of another type it will throw exception.

Comment: Dispose definitely does work. its that you are not looping through the disposing the correct controls thats not working.

Comment: dam the problem is not inside its in the foreach, foreach(Orb o in this.Controls) should be at least foreach(Control o in this.Controls)

Comment: sorry to bother again but the thing with the for and not foreach is you are modifying the colection its iterating so it will remove 1 and break out.

Comment: @terrybozzio not true in this case.

Comment: @terrybozzio are you happy now? i made a method to return all the `Orbs` then a foreach to remove them all.